# how to convert string of integers and Lists to arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a situation where I want to convert a string into an `ArrayList THAT CONTAINS INTEGERS AND OTHER ARRAYLISTS.` In my string, I can have an arbitrary number of words which I want added into the `ArrayList` object:

```
String s = "[2,5,9,8,1,[5,7],9,8,[9,6,9,8],8,9]";
```

I did some work:

```
String testdata = "[25,645,[36,65],65]";
ArrayList<Integer> arrayInt = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner readFile = new Scanner(testdata)) {
    Pattern digitsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
        Matcher m = digitsPattern.matcher(readFile.nextLine());
        while (m.find())
            arrayInt.add(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)));
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
[25, 645, 36, 65, 65]
```

IWhat  i  want  is  this : `[25,645,[36,65],65]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[` and `]`, then use Scanner with `,` delimiter (or use `[`, `]` and `,` as Scanner's delimiters - this regex should do the trick `[\\[\\],]+`).

Also to avoid `Integer.parseInt` use `Scanner#nextInt` which returns `int`.

EDIT:

If you are willing to accept list which will contain numbers as floating point types like `double`s you could try JSON serialization/deserialization tools like gson.

```
String testdata = "[25, 645, [36, 65], 65]";
List fromJson = new Gson().fromJson(testdata, List.class);
System.out.println(fromJson);
```

Output: `[25.0, 645.0, [36.0, 65.0], 65.0]`.

Comment: think  you  for the answer , excuse me ibut what i want is  to  have an Arraylist THAT CONTAINS INTEGERS AND OTHER ARRAYLISTS

Comment: From your question: "*result is: `[25, 645, 36, 65, 65]`*", "*Is there any way to do it in a simpler way...*" suggests that result part from your question is correct and you are simply asking how to rewrite it using simpler code. What you said in comment above doesn't confirm your text from question. So please clarify what you are trying to do (what should be correct result since my approach would produce same as `result` from OP). BTW Lists are usually used to store single type of elements, If you want to have many levels of elements you should probably build some kind of three structure.

Comment: excuse  me it's my fault  that  did not explain well ,  i  did  Edit  my  question     what  i  want  as  result  is this :  [25,645,[36,65],65]
think  you  verry much for your help

Comment: If you are willing to accept List which will contain numbers as floating points then you can use some JSON serialization tool. For instance with gson library code like `new Gson().fromJson(testdata, List.class)` would return ArrayList which will contain: `[25.0, 645.0, [36.0, 65.0], 65.0]`.

Comment: think  you  for  the  idea  of using  json

Comment: I am not aware of such possibility, at least not with gson.

Comment: OK  think  you  that's  what i found ... i  did  change  the aproach ...using  a  classic  if else  algorithm

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList<E>` is typed, ie. you specify what single type `<E>` it can hold. For example, you have specified that `arrayInt` holds `Integers`, ie. `E` is `Integer`. This `ArrayList` cannot also then hold `ArrayList<Integer>`.

In order to meet your requirements you will need to define a type that can act as both a single `Integer` or a collection of `Integers`. This is usually implemented using the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).